# Cordova Android apk isn't available after successful build on Azure Devops

Tags: cordova, azure-devops

Our time is using Azure Devops and we want to build an Android App via Cordova. Given that the [Cordova integration from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-cordova-tasks) is unfortunately deprecated and doesn't support newer versions of Cordova, my approach is to build the apk via an npm task.

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'build android cordova app'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: true
    customCommand: 'run cordova-build-android'
```

Afterwards, I want to sign it via:

```
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/cordova/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk'
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'xxx.keystore'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: 'xxx'
```

The first task runs successfully, the second fails and says it can't find the `.apk` even through when I run the cordova-build-android locally on my own computer the resulting `.apk` ends up in `/cordova/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`.

Comment: Run the pipeline with `system.debug` = true and check the first task logs. also, add a cmd task, cd to the folder and print the files.

Comment: Does the `Npm@1` task indeed generate the `.apk`? If yes, you'd better check the detailed logs to find out the location of `.apk`. Then sync it with the value of task properties `apkFiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I had to run `cordova prepare` before building in the buildprocess.

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'cordova prepare'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      verbose: true
      customCommand: 'run cordova-prepare'
```

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here! You can accept this answer:-)